# jQuery animate font color

Tags: jquery

what is wrong with my jQuery code here?

```
    <script>$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".a").hover(function()
        {
            $(this).find('h2.article-title, p.readmore').stop().animate({'color': '#000000'}, 'normal');
            $(this).find('img.a').stop().animate({'opacity': '0'}, 'normal');
        },function()
        {
            $(this).find('h2.article-title, p.readmore').stop().animate({'color': '#606060'}, 'normal');
            $(this).find('img.a').stop().animate({'opacity': '1'}, 'normal');
        });
    });</script>
```

The opacity animate is working well **but not the color** and when I use the following  code it's working:

```
$(this).find('h2.article-title, p.readmore').css('color', 'black');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animating colors does not work unless you include a library for animating colors.
jQuery **does not** animate colors by default.

There's several to choose from, and jQuery UI also includes color animation but has a large footprint and should probably be avoided if all you need is the color animations.

https://jqueryui.com/
http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/